# How MySql handles composite index

Tags: mysql, indexing

```
CREATE TABLE campaigns (
  domain varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  campaign_id varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  node_id varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  subscriber_id varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  message varchar(21000) DEFAULT NULL,
  log_time datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  log_type varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  campaign_name varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL

  KEY `campid_domain_logtype_logtime_subid_index` (`campaign_id`,`domain`,`log_type`,`log_time`,`subscriber_id`),
  KEY `domain_logtype_logtime_index` (`domain`,`log_type`,`log_time`)

)
```

The above one is schema of our table in MySql. One campaign can have multiple nodes.

The index `campid_domain_logtype_logtime_subid_index` works fine with reports w.r.t specific campaign.

recently we added node_id into this table, now we need reports w.r.t specific node .

So now I'm planning to change our covering index like following to support both campaign level and node level reports

`campid_nodeid_domain_logtype_logtime_subid_index`.

Example query for reports on specific campaign

```
SELECT log_type,
        count(DISTINCT subscriber_id) AS count,
        count(subscriber_id) AS total 
FROM stats.campaign_logs USE INDEX(campid_domain_logtype_logtime_subid_index) 
where domain = 'aaa' AND campaign_id='12345' AND 
  log_type in ('EMAIL_SENT','EMAIL_OPENED','EMAIL_CLICKED')
  AND log_time BETWEEN CONVERT_TZ('2016-03-13 00:00:00','+01:30','+00:00') AND CONVERT_TZ('2016-04-13 23:59:59','+01:30','+00:00') 
GROUP BY log_type;
```

Example query for reports on specific node id of specific campaign

```
SELECT 
   log_type,
   count(DISTINCT subscriber_id) AS count,
   count(subscriber_id) AS total 
FROM stats.campaign_logs USE INDEX(campid_domain_logtype_logtime_subid_index) 
where domain='aaa' AND campaign_id='12345' AND 
      node_id = '56789' and 
      log_type in ('EMAIL_SENT','EMAIL_OPENED','EMAIL_CLICKED') 
      AND log_time BETWEEN CONVERT_TZ('2016-03-13 00:00:00','+01:30','+00:00') AND CONVERT_TZ('2016-04-13 23:59:59','+01:30','+00:00') 
GROUP BY log_type;
```

So my question does this new index satisfy our both kind of queries effectively if not please suggest suitable indexes.

**UPDATE:**

Data distribution in table

1 Domain can have multiple campaigns for example 20

1 Campaign can have multiple nodes for example 10

1 Campaign can have multiple log types for example 50

1 Campaign can have lot of subscribers for example 100,000

1 Campaign can have lot of log times because we use mysql now() when we store log.

UPDATE

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According your queries, you should create the following index

```
KEY `campid_domain_logtype_logtime_subid_index` (
    `campaign_id`, 
    `domain`, 
    `log_time`, 
    `node_id`, 
    `subscriber_id`
);
```

`campaign_id` and `log_time` are used always, `node_id` just in some cases.

Not sure that you should left `domain` and  `subscriber_id`

Do not see all of them in queries.

`log_type` is debatable as well. I do not believe that it has good selectivity and just waste a space.

**Updated**

According our communications in comments

- Campaign id is primary column
- Domain is the second. Try to play, maybe you should remove it
- Log time for range selecting
- Node ID for you specific queries

If you often use subscriber_id in queries - add it.

And I would remove log_type.

As option, try to create the following index:

```
 Campaign id, Log time, Node ID  (subscriber_id ?)
```

Comment: Could you add selectivity  of each field - How much unique values it has

Comment: how much domains in your table?

Comment: it is arround 4k now. some domains having only few rows and some domains having  large number of rows in table.

Comment: and last query, which fields will be used always in queries in WHERE clause

Comment: In where class we always use domain and campaign_id columns always. Only node id we uses sometimes in where class.

Answer (score 0):

Basic rules for building the best index:

1. include column(s) with '=', in any order;
2. include one other column, preferably a range.

So you need `INDEX(domain, campaign_id, log_time)` for the first query.  `log_type` gets in the way; don't include it.

(added) `INDEX(campaign_id, node_id, domain, log_time)` is needed for the 'new' query.

In both cases, `log_time` should be last; the other columns can be in any order.  Rearranging the order may help with other queries.  No one index is optimal for both queries.

Then, don't use `USE INDEX`; it may backfire.

[More cookbook tips](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

The better solution is more complex:  Build and maintain summary tables of various counters/sums that are frequently needed.  (Perhaps using 30-minute time ranges.)  Caveat:  `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` cannot be handled in a summary table.

Why are those ids `VARCHAR(50)`, not `INT UNSIGNED`?  You would also benefit from normalizing other fields such as `domain`.  `log_type` could be a 1-byte `ENUM`.

Do you really need all columns to be NULLable?

Is any combination of those columns unique?  InnoDB really likes to have a `PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried with your suggested index but its taking time to get results and you didn't replied on my node_id column index. could you reply on it.

Comment: The original query needs one index; the new query with node_id needs another.  (I added a couple of paragraphs to my answer.)

Comment: How many rows are touched to run these queries?  If it is millions, perhaps we should talk about Summary tables.